# About interpretation of Landau notation.

Tags: analysis

I have a question about Landau notation for complex analysis.

Let $f(z)$ be a complex function and $g(z)$ be a real valued function of complex valuable which satisfies $g(z) \ge 0$. Then we write
$$f(z)=O(g(z))$$
when these functions satisfy
$$|f(z)|\le Cg(z)$$
for some constant $C>0$.
For example, We use this notation so that
\begin{equation}
f(z)=g(z)+O(h(z)) \quad (1) \\
e^{f(z)}=e^{g(z)}e^{O(h(z))} \quad (2)
\end{equation}
for appropriate functions. I think that the second example (2) means
$$ |e^{f(z)-g(z)}|\le e^{Ch(z)}.$$

My question is about taking exponential or log of Landau notation. When (1) is true, then we get
$$ e^{f(z)}=e^{g(z)}e^{O(h(z))}$$
because
$$|e^{f(z)-g(z)}|=e^{\Re(f(z)-g(z))}\le e^{|f(z)-g(z)|} \le e^{Ch(z)}$$
for certain constant $C>0$. But when (2) is true, (1) is not always true. We can get only
$$ \log|e^{f(z)-g(z)}| = \Re(f(z)-g(z)) \le \log(ch(z)).$$
We cannot get (1) from (2).

So I think that we can take exponential of Landau notation but we cannot take log. Is this correct? Or Do I have a mistake of my interpretation of the formula (2)?